# Need a shortcode that outputs all attachment ids from a post

Tags: wordpress, gallery, attachment, shortcode

I'm in need of a wordpress shortcode that outputs all the image attachments ids of a post separated by commas.

Something similar to [get-image-ids] which outputs "11,12,13" as I need it to use inside another shortcode, a Divi one. I have very basic knowledge of PHP.

It is something like this, only this uses a meta key "wpcf-gallery-images" coming from a custom post type. I'd just need the IDs of the image attachments of the current post.

```
function prefix_get_img_ids($atts) {
global $post;

 $images = (array) get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-gallery-images', false); // cast to array in case there is only one item
 $ids = array();

 global $wpdb;

 foreach($images as $img) {
  $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$img'";
  $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
  $ids[] = $id;
 }

 return implode(",",$ids);
}
add_shortcode("get-image-ids", "prefix_get_img_ids");
```

Then you can use [gallery ids="[get-image-ids]"] that it is what I would need.

Answer (score 0):

What gallery plugin are you using?  Seems like this should be supported already.

The only way to do this would be to modify the gallery plugin to call do_shortcode() on that specific parameter

e.g.

```
$atts['get-image-ids'] = do_shortcode($atts['get-image-ids']);
```

This however would not be the correct way to handle this, as you should update the gallery plugin itself to do the **get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-gallery-images', false);** code - instead of nesting shortcodes (via do_shortcode), which is like using a sledgehammer to kill a fly.

Tell me which gallery plugin you are using and I can probably find the correct way, I would imagine it's already supported somehow.

Comment: No, no, forget about the meta key. It was just an example that works when you need to output the contents of a repeater field in a custom post type. It doesn't apply to my needs. Instead of the contents of a repeater field, I just need the attachment ids of the images linked to the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use the Gallery DIVI Module for this.
This is the shortcode DIVI uses:

```
[et_pb_gallery _builder_version="3.24" gallery_ids="23219,23218,23217,23215,23216,23214,23213,23212,23211,23209" posts_number="20" show_title_and_caption="off" show_pagination="off" zoom_icon_color="#ffffff" hover_overlay_color="rgba(6,83,182,0.5)" hover_icon="%%47%%" hover_icon_tablet="%%47%%" hover_icon_phone="%%47%%" box_shadow_vertical_image_tablet="0px" box_shadow_blur_image_tablet="40px" box_shadow_spread_image_tablet="0px" text_shadow_horizontal_length="text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" text_shadow_horizontal_length_tablet="0px" text_shadow_vertical_length="text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" text_shadow_vertical_length_tablet="0px" text_shadow_blur_strength="text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" text_shadow_blur_strength_tablet="1px" title_text_shadow_horizontal_length="title_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" title_text_shadow_horizontal_length_tablet="0px" title_text_shadow_vertical_length="title_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" title_text_shadow_vertical_length_tablet="0px" title_text_shadow_blur_strength="title_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" title_text_shadow_blur_strength_tablet="1px" caption_text_shadow_horizontal_length="caption_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" caption_text_shadow_horizontal_length_tablet="0px" caption_text_shadow_vertical_length="caption_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" caption_text_shadow_vertical_length_tablet="0px" caption_text_shadow_blur_strength="caption_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" caption_text_shadow_blur_strength_tablet="1px" pagination_text_shadow_horizontal_length="pagination_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" pagination_text_shadow_horizontal_length_tablet="0px" pagination_text_shadow_vertical_length="pagination_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" pagination_text_shadow_vertical_length_tablet="0px" pagination_text_shadow_blur_strength="pagination_text_shadow_style,%91object Object%93" pagination_text_shadow_blur_strength_tablet="1px" box_shadow_horizontal_tablet="0px" box_shadow_vertical_tablet="0px" box_shadow_blur_tablet="40px" box_shadow_spread_tablet="0px" z_index_tablet="500" /]
```

What I'd like to do is subtitute this `gallery_ids="23219,23218,23217,23215,23216,23214,23213,23212,23211,23209"`

with a shortcode that outputs the IDs of the attached images to the post separated por commas, like this:

```
gallery_ids="[get-image-ids]"
```

That way I can use a page template for my custom post type.